# How to stop people from settling in our area?

Tags: rust

How can I prevent people from building at a specific area?
I'm not talking about the size of 1 or 5 cupboards, but the entire hacker-valley (see map below, north east).

The first Idea was to greate a wall along the riverborder to riverlands-north. But since latest patch, walls decay very quick and we would have to repair it the whole day (not fun).

Before you claim, this is unethical or whatever:
We are about 1/10 of servers population, also, the game allows this behavior and so do the server rules. The server is at a state where the gameplay isn't about survival of a person, but about survival of the own clan. There are massive wars, with borders, multiple defense lines, escape rooms all over our land and so on. So if noobs have no fun because of this, sorry, but they're on the wrong server.

[image]

Comment: We already set up some 1x1 armored cubes with cupbords inside around our mainbase, but they have to be repaired at least one time a day or they get vulnerable. setting these around the mainbase is okay, but the whole claimed land seems impossible to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

If you have that much manpower you may want to explore having several shifts of scouts that patrol through your borders looking for intruders/nakeds, as well as gathering resources. This would allow you to maintain an income using these people for this purpose, as well as warning your clan before they get set up enough to be tough to dig out.

I think a wall would definitely help keep people out but it is expensive. I think you should look at defenses as deterrents instead of solutions. Seeing structures or defensive structures would probably discourage some people from settling in your land as it would be likely to be opposed, and *quickly* at that. Use them to 'funnel' enemies to positions that would be advantageous to you to attack/defend from. Enemies are less likely to attack defenses that they can simply move around than walls that completely prevent access (and would probably be seen as a challenge to those willing enough to test your defenses anyway). Use this to your advantage.

Another good way to discourage settling is to remove what many of them come there for: resources. If you wall off or tower up small areas around key resources, you can deny that income to enemies. Additionally, this will make your own mining/extracting safer since you will have a defensive position to fight from if attacked. This also has an added bonus of nakeds not even *knowing* there are resources there. There's no way for them to know if that's a base structure or a resource node just by looking at it.